# How to set specific elements of an array with minimal code C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I was wondering if there is an easy way to set more than one element of an array in a single line of code. For example, instead of:

```
int Array[10];
Array[4] = 100;
Array[7] = 100;
```

Is there some way to do something like the following?

```
int Array[10];
Array[4 & 7] = 100;
```

I know the above code doesn't work, but I can't really think of any other way to display my question. Anyhow, thanks in advance to anyone who would like to share their opinion :)

Comment: Valid language semantics aren't opinions, unless you're on the language committee.

Comment: Array[4]= Array[7] = 100; this is single line :)

Comment: You can also create a terse pointer or reference in local scope `{ int* a = Array; a[4] = a[7] = 100; }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int array[10];
array[4] = array[7] = 100;
array[4] = 100, array[7] = 100;
4[array] = 7[array] = 100;
```

EDIT:

You may want to use loops for a somewhat dynamic setting of elements

```
int i, array[10], array_element[3] = { 3, 5, 6 };
for (i = 0; array_element[i] && array[array_element[i]]; i++) array[array_element[i]] = 100;
```

Another option is to define a function if by 'minimal' code you mean abstraction

```
overlord::set(array, 100, "3, 5, 6");
overlord::set(array, 100, "{ 3, 5, 6 }");
overlord::set(array, "3: 200, 5: 400, 6: 500");
```

Either way you won't find "DYNAMIC" language features in C++ or C. You'll have to implement an abstraction over basic existing functionality to be able to get that silly dynamic typing.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do it this way

```
 int Array[10];
 Array[4] = Array[7] = 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set a range of elements you can use a for loop

```
int array[10];
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    array[i] = 100;
}
```

You can also do it for only certain numbers by using this trick

```
int nums[2] = { 4,7 }; //Positions you wish to set
for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
    array[nums[i]] = 100;  //nums[0] = 4, array[4] 
                           //nums[1] = 7, array[7]
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to set a range of elements, you can use [`std::fill`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill/).

Answer (score 0):

You have this perfectly readable code:

```
int Array[10];
Array[4] = 100;
Array[7] = 100;
```

And you want to "set more than one element of an array in a single line of code." Okay:

```
int Array[10];
Array[4] = 100; Array[7] = 100;
```

But why would you? Is there a newline shortage that I haven't heard about?